# Count of distinct strings in comma separated list (string)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example let's say I've got a table as such:

| PrimaryKey | List |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | thing, stuff |
| 2 | thing |
| 3 | stuff, doodad, thing |
| 4 | stuff, thing |

Where each value in the 'List' column is a string with words separated by a comma. I'd like to get the count of each word that appears in that column so that I end up with this:

| Word | Count |
| --- | --- |
| thing | 4 |
| stuff | 3 |
| doodad | 1 |

I've seen a lot of really similar questions, but can't seem to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the SPLIT_TO_TABLE function:

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ST (PrimaryKey INT, List STRING);
  
INSERT INTO ST  
SELECT * FROM VALUES
(1, 'thing, stuff'),
(2, 'thing'),
(3, 'stuff, doodad, thing'),
(4, 'stuff, thing') AS t(PrimaryKey, List);
```

Solution:

```
SELECT TRIM(L.VALUE) AS Word, COUNT(TRIM(L.VALUE)) AS Count
  FROM ST,
  LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(ST.List, ',') AS L
 GROUP BY TRIM(L.VALUE);
```

Reference: [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html#split-to-table)

Comment: This worked like a charm and gave me a great starting point to learn more! SQL/DB stuff isn't my forte and this gave me a good foothold to start learning more. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
create table test_1 as (       
 SELECT fld1 FROM (
 SELECT 'thing, stuff' fld1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'thing' fld1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'stuff, doodad, thing' fld1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'stuff, thing' fld1 
   )
   );
   
select count(*), fld1 from (    
 SELECT  trim(value) as fld1 FROM test_1,   lateral split_to_Table(test_1.fld1,',') 
  order by value
) group by fld1
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the above answers show how to use [SPLIT_TO_TABLE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) which is great -> you can also use [strtok_split_to_table()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table.html) This function allows multiple delimiters (SPLIT_TO_TABLE allows just one) which is pretty cool (making it easier in the real world).

I changed some of the commas to a hyphens so you can see it still work.

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run:

```
with a as (SELECT * FROM VALUES
(1, 'thing, stuff'),
(2, 'thing'),
(3, 'stuff, doodad - thing'), 
(4, 'stuff- thing') AS t(pk, l))

select 
    value::string answer,count(1) 
from 
     a 
    ,lateral strtok_split_to_table(a.l,(', |-' ))  
group by 
     answer
```

Comment: This is great to know! Luckily I've got control over the backend that's responsible for generating the data and I don't think there should be any strings that bring about the requirements for needing multiple delimiters, but there's always a chance that it could happen. Thank you for the extra mile!